# SQL search error: Every derived table must have its own alias

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a following query:

```
String queryString = "SELECT pk" 
                + " FROM ({{SELECT COUNT(*) as num, {Book.pk} as pk"
                + " FROM {Rental JOIN Book ON {Rental.product} = {Book.pk}}" 
                + " GROUP BY {Rental.product}, {Book.pk}"
                + " ORDER BY num DESC LIMIT ?limit}})";
```

When I execute this, I get the error "Every derived table must have its own alias". What I'm missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"SELECT pk" 
            + " FROM ({{SELECT COUNT(*) as num, {Book.pk} as pk"
            + " FROM {Rental JOIN Book ON {Rental.product} = {Book.pk}}" 
            + " GROUP BY {Rental.product}, {Book.pk}"
            + " ORDER BY num DESC LIMIT ?limit}}) t";
                                                  ^
```

Just add an alias for the derived table

Comment: Thank you on the quick reply, I will try that now!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is pretty clear from the error message.  You need an alias on the subquery.

But, because you don't need a subquery, your method is overly complicated:

```
  SELECT {Book.pk} as pk" +
" FROM {Rental JOIN Book ON {Rental.product} = {Book.pk}}" +
" GROUP BY {Rental.product}, {Book.pk}" +
" ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
" LIMIT ?limit
```